# Understanding ELF TBSS and TDATA section loading

Tags: elf, thread-local-storage

My elf file's sections are as follows

```
      Size              EntSize          Flags  Link  Info  Align
  [ 0]                   NULL             0000000000000000  00000000
       0000000000000000  0000000000000000           0     0     0
  [ 1] .text             PROGBITS         fffffffff7e020b0  000000b0
       0000000000074f50  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     16
  [ 2] .rodata           PROGBITS         fffffffff7e77000  00075000
       0000000000014000  0000000000000000  AM       0     0     16
  [ 3] .eh_frame_hdr     PROGBITS         fffffffff7e8b000  00089000
       000000000000000c  0000000000000000   A       0     0     4
  [ 4] .data             PROGBITS         fffffffff7e8b010  00089010
       0000000000001ff0  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     16
  [ 5] .bss              NOBITS           fffffffff7e8d000  0008b000
       0000000000014000  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     4096
  [ 6] .got              PROGBITS         fffffffff7ea1000  0009f000
       0000000000001000  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     8
  [ 7] .tdata            PROGBITS         fffffffff7ea2000  000a0000
       000000000000b000  0000000000000000 WAT       0     0     8
  [ 8] .tbss             NOBITS           fffffffff7ead000  000ab000
       000000000000012a  0000000000000000 WAT       0     0     8
  [ 9] .debug_abbrev     PROGBITS         0000000000000000  000ab000
       000000000001a8d4  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [10] .debug_info       PROGBITS         0000000000000000  000c58d4
       000000000016c624  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [11] .debug_aranges    PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00231ef8
       0000000000024130  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [12] .debug_ranges     PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00256028
       000000000004bfa0  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [13] .debug_str        PROGBITS         0000000000000000  002a1fc8
       0000000000123ecd  0000000000000001  MS       0     0     1
  [14] .debug_pubnames   PROGBITS         0000000000000000  003c5e95
       000000000005da3c  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [15] .debug_pubtypes   PROGBITS         0000000000000000  004238d1
       00000000000a1e07  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [16] .debug_frame      PROGBITS         0000000000000000  004c56d8
       0000000000056c10  0000000000000000           0     0     8
  [17] .debug_line       PROGBITS         0000000000000000  0051c2e8
       00000000000b5c55  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [18] .debug_loc        PROGBITS         0000000000000000  005d1f3d
       000000000000628c  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [19] .symtab           SYMTAB           0000000000000000  005d81d0
       0000000000015a20  0000000000000018          21   2565     8
  [20] .shstrtab         STRTAB           0000000000000000  005edbf0
       00000000000000da  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [21] .strtab           STRTAB           0000000000000000  005edcca
       000000000004783e  0000000000000000           0     0     1
```

and the program headers are

```
Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)
Entry point 0xfffffffff7e39be0
There are 2 program headers, starting at offset 64

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  LOAD           0x0000000000000000 0xfffffffff7e02000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x00000000000ab000 0x00000000000ab12a  RWE    0x1000
  TLS            0x00000000000a0000 0xfffffffff7ea2000 0x00000000000a0000
                 0x000000000000b000 0x000000000000b12a  RW     0x8

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     .text .rodata .eh_frame_hdr .data .bss .got .tdata
   01     .tdata .tbss
```

The TLS section's total size is as expected being the size of `tdata + tbss` sections.
From the TLS handling [document](https://akkadia.org/drepper/tls.pdf), i expect that `tdata` and `tbss` sections will be right before the `fs` register's pointed value and thus the total size would be `0xb12a`.

But one of the variables which use `thread_local` have an offset of `fs - 0xb130` which is outside of the expected TLS size.
I am trying to understand why the variable is not offset to at-most `0xb12a` but more than that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the size of TLS here is `0xb12a`. The alignment of `0x8` will make the TLS pointer move to `0xb130` which is the address of variable observed here.